# Implement pdf.js in Apache Cordova

Tags: pdf, typescript, pdf.js, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am trying to develop an Apache Cordova Application with Visual Studio 2013 for Android, using Typescript. I am unable to display my PDF. My program begins by downloading the PDF file to the Android Device from a website. After this though, I am unaware as to how to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) to display the downloaded PDF. I tried looking at the examples and implementing them on a HTML file in IE, but I've been unsuccessful with all attempts to display any kind of PDF, so a sample that works, but not on Android is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> so a sample that works, but not on Android is also appreciated.

The PDF js hello world : http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html You can open it on android too.